# PostCSS import as reference instead of inline

Tags: less, postcss

Less has this handy [option](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) whereby the referenced importing file will be only used to resolve variables but it will not be inlined. Is there any way to do the same with [postcss-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-import) or any other similar PostCSS plugin?

The below block of code is how this behaviour works in Less. I'd like to achieve similar behaviour with PostCSS.

```
@import (reference) "foo.less";

/* Content of "foo.less" won't be inlined but variables on this different file will be resolved */
.rules {
    width: @big; /* Declared in "foo.less". It will be resolved to 1200px (for example) */
}
```

Comment: Your example is missing some key information. When/how is `@big` defined?

Comment: I've made some clarifications on the text.